# Get index inside javascript foreach loop

Tags: javascript, foreach

Whilest reading the docs: [MDN Array forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) I'm trying to get the index inside the foreach loop but just not getting it..

```js
var BANG = {};

BANG.boom = function (arr) {
    this.array = arr;
    
    this.start = function() {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(
            this.array,
            (function (blubb, index) {
                window.setInterval(
                    this.hello(blubb, index),
                    1500
                );
            }).bind(this)
        );
    };

    this.hello = function(blubb, index) {
        alert(blubb, index)
    };
};

xxx = new BANG.boom(['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz']);
xxx.start();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" - not using a for loop

Comment: What do you mean "just not getting it"?

Comment: Yes, you **are** getting the index: https://jsfiddle.net/9egp6qab/ You're just not using it properly; [Mateusz's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39595489/157247) demonstrates how to use it properly.

Comment: `console.log(index+':'+blubb)` shows me the index - alert does not do commas

Comment: Side note: `arr` is already an array, no need for the `Array.prototype.forEach.call` hoop jumping.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder always appreciate your comments! Can you please explain the last one with `hoop jumping` a little more please. I'm doing something obviously wrong but don't know how to do better.. Thanks

Comment: Instead of `Array.prototype.forEach.call(arr, ...` just use `arr.forEach(...` (**if** you know that `arr` will definitely be an array, which it will above).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OK, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works, but `alert` takes only one argument, so you're not seeing it. :)

```js
var BANG = {};

BANG.boom = function (arr) {
    this.array = arr;
    
    this.start = function() {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(
            this.array,
            (function (blubb, index) {
                window.setInterval(
                    this.hello(blubb, index),
                    1500
                );
            }).bind(this)
        );
    };

    this.hello = function(blubb, index) {
        alert(index+":"+blubb);    // only one argument
        console.log(index,blubb); // console does understand the comma
    };
};

xxx = new BANG.boom(['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz']);
xxx.start();
```